# Binary overview of project dependency C++

Tags: c++, linker

While using MSVC, does making a project (A, exe) depend on another project (B, static lib) increases the size of the exe file by the size of the lib? Or the linkage will be done only across  the compilation units needed from project B?

Comment: Is the *lib* static or dynamic?  A static lib will increase the size of the executable; a dynamic or shared lib will not.

Comment: B is a static library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B is a static library, the size of A.exe would increase *roughly* by B's size. Two factors can potentially intervene (in optimized builds):

(1) Elimination of unused functions and data ([/OPT:REF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx)), that typically reduces the executable size,

(2) [Link time code generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx)  - when activated for B.lib - typically employs extensive inlining and serves to increase the executable size.

[Edit]

I didn't notice this part of your question: indeed when linking a static library by default the linker will load only the obj files that are referenced. This default behaviour can be overriden per reference with the obscure 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' checkbox on the references pane ([some details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/05/03/flexible-project-to-project-references.aspx)), or for all references with the '[Link Library dependency inputs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/024awkd1.aspx)' linker property.